# Can't install php on el capitan

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I just got a mac and i try to install php like what i have on windows. I downloaded homebrew, git, vscode... But when i type brew install php or brew install php@7.4 i doesn't work.

I got the following error.

Thank's for your help

```
==> Installing php dependency: pcre
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/pcre/8.44 --enable-utf8 --enable-pcre
==> make
==> make test
Last 15 lines from /Users/admin/Library/Logs/Homebrew/pcre/03.make:
============================================================================
# TOTAL: 6
# PASS:  5
# SKIP:  0
# XFAIL: 0
# FAIL:  1
# XPASS: 0
# ERROR: 0
============================================================================
See ./test-suite.log
============================================================================
make[3]: *** [test-suite.log] Error 1
make[2]: *** [check-TESTS] Error 2
make[1]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make: *** [check] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!


Error: You are using macOS 10.11.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your version of macOS is too old and not supported, as it says in the error log. https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

You need to have at least macOS Mojave (10.14).

Comment: So for PHP on macOS 10.11, the only way to install is manual compilation then?

Comment: I don't know about that. I'm just trying to troubleshoot here and that would probably be the first step. Why not just update your OS? How old is the hardware?

Comment: MacBook Pro 2009

Comment: I'm pretty sure i can install it with a tips. 
I got a similar error for another package (i don't remember which one) and i got a trick that finally work well.

Comment: It may be better if i install docker maybe no ? If i use docker to install PHP